# getOrderShippingCost() is called more than once in Prestashop 1.6.x

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, carrier

I am building a Carrier module in Prestashop 1.6.x and at the moment I am having a problem with the abstract method getOrderShippingCost().

It is called 6 times and I cannot find out why.

I need a way of tracking why is it called that many times.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I got it why it is called multiple times.

The method is called as many times as many carriers you've got registered in the shop.